# How to consolidate a DataFrame inplace

Tags: python, pandas

I am now working on inserting a lot of columns to a DataFrame with functions. Due to the size of the DataFrame, making copies (e.g. df = pd.concat([df, df_insert])) is difficult, so the columns are inserted inplace with a function (the function does not return a DataFrame, it modifies the input DataFrame instead). Is there a DataFrame method to decrease the df._mgr.nblocks count INPLACE to prevent the 'DataFrame is highly fragmented' warning?

Before pandas=2.0.0, some functions, e.g. df.mean, consolidates the function inplace. Now this function does not consolidate inplace, causing the warning 'DataFrame is highly fragmented'.

Comment: If you have this warning, this means that you just `insert` (is similar) repeatedly. This is inefficient, if you want to change that you **must** modify the logic to **not modify the source in place**. A good strategy might be to generate all new columns and to `update` the dataframe **once**

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Refractoring the code seems to be the best solution right now.